# Recursion with for loop never stops. Can't find my mistake

Tags: java, android, for-loop, recursion

I'm creating a music player for Android and I'm trying to implement a timer feature where you can set a duration and the app gives you a playlist with exactly this duration. I tought it would be good to do this with recursion. Here is my code:

Variables:

```
maxLength = [any value in seconds] ... Wanted duration for the ArrayList with songs
currentLength = 0 ... current Duration of the ArrayList
timerSongs = new ArrayList<Song>() ... the ArrayList with the playlist
allSongs ... ArrayList with all the songs I have on my device
```

Here's the void that gets called to add items to the timerSongs

```
private void addSongs(int index, long maxLength){

    if (currentLength<=maxLength){
        timerSongs.add(allSongs.get(index));

        currentLength = currentLength
            + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(allSongs.get(index).getDuration());

        for (int i = 0; i < allSongs.size() && currentLength != maxLength; i++){
            Log.e("Index", String.valueOf(i));
            addSongs(i, maxLength);
        }
    } else {
        currentLength = currentLength
            - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timerSongs.get(timerSongs.size()-1).getDuration());
        timerSongs.remove(timerSongs.size()-1);
    }
}
```

EDIT: What I'm trying to do is:

1. Let the app add songs to the arrayList (timerSongs) until it's too long
2. Remove the song that was too long
3. Add the next song and try again if the duration (currentLength) is too long. If yes, remove it again
4. Do step 3 for all the next songs
5. If duration still isn't correct, set a new forelast song, and do the steps above again

   and so on...

I can't find a mistake... But `Log.e("Index", String.valueOf(i));` always gives me the same value: 0. After some time the app crashes because of a stack overflow. So it seems like the recursion never stops. Does anyone see a mistake in my code? What's the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you think this would be a good use for recursion?

Comment: I've no idea what you are trying to do but this almost certainly not the way to do it...but since I've no idea what you're trying to do I can't really point you in a better way.

Comment: Because the program first has to add songs and after that go backwards and try all combinations to get the wanted result. But it's not important why I think that. I want help to find my mistake..

Comment: The problem is the for loop starts at `i=0` and enters the recursion, then the for loop starts at `i=0` and enters the recursion, then for loop starts at `i=0` and enters the recursion... see the problem?

Comment: @cricket_007 but if the condition (currentLength<=maxLength) is false the recursion should stop and the loop should go on with i=1 , shouldn't it?

Comment: In theory, yes, but according to your error, that isn't happening

Comment: What you are trying to do here is basically the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Where your playlist is a knapsack, the songs are the objects, and the length is the capacity/size.

Comment: Shouldn't it be currentLength < maxLength instead of <= because with <= it would become too much if the values are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

If someone is interested, here's the code:

```
private void addSongs(int index, long maxLength){

        if (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(currentLength) <= maxLength){
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < songList.size() && TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(currentLength) != maxLength; i++){
                    timerSongs.add(songList.get(i));
                    currentLength = currentLength + songList.get(i).getDuration();
                    addSongs(i, maxLength);
            }
            if (i >= songList.size()){
                currentLength = currentLength - timerSongs.get(timerSongs.size()-1).getDuration();
                timerSongs.remove(timerSongs.size()-1);
            }
        } else {
            currentLength = currentLength - timerSongs.get(timerSongs.size()-1).getDuration();
            timerSongs.remove(timerSongs.size()-1);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop will never "++" because it waits for the addSongs method to finish executing. When the for loop is run with i == 0,  the same method is executed creating a for loop again and again which always has 0 as i's base int. This, logically, doesn't stop. Try replacing the for loop with this:

```
if(currentLength != maxLength){
  addSongs(index + 1, maxLength);
}
```

Comment: The recursive call will stop when `currentLength > maxLength`, and hit the `else`, decrement `currentLength`, then return to `i++`

Answer (score 0):

Well, although I personally think your solution using recursion like that is pretty bad, you should change this line

```
for (int i = 0; i < allSongs.size() && currentLength != maxLength; i++){
```

To

```
for (int i = 0; i < allSongs.size() && currentLength <= maxLength; i++){
```

Comment: `currentLength <= maxLength` is already handled in the if statement, so only `i < allSongs.size()` is necessary